# Update build number from installer output in TFS (Advanced Installer Updates Configuration Project)

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core, azure-devops, advanced-installer

I'm currently building a project on TFS and using the Advanced Installer build tasks to create an installer and the updater text file.  The 2 Advanced Installer Build tasks on TFS are:

---

1) The first one creates the installer from the Publish Build Artifacts (This works fine)
2) The second one grabs that installer, should get the build number of the installer file and create the updater.txt file with the proper information. (This does not work)

---

When I run this project on my computer, I have to manually upload the installer executable from the `Update Installer/File path` section so the project can recognize that is a new build number. When I click on `Build` and it outputs the correct updater.txt file.

---

Is there a way for the Advanced Installer Updates Configuration Project in TFS to automatically detect that the installer .exe changed?
Thank you

[image: TFS]

Build installer settings:
Project:  Installer.aip
Build: 
Output Package Name: Installer
Output Package Folder: /Output/
Command Line Arguments:

Build Updater settings:
Project:  Updater.aip
Build: /Output/Installer.exe
Command Line Arguments: 
[Link to configuration files on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iu6uakO8uN7fJmXvo8OL7HeIjP4lTuDI)

Comment: What're tasks of your build and release definition?

Comment: When I add a build definition on TFS, then add a Agent Phase to the Build Process, then add tasks like Nuget Tool Installer, Visual Studio Build, Publish Build Artifacts, etc.

Comment: Can you share the simple sample and detail log on the OneDrive (Set system.debug variable to true, queue build and share this log)?

Comment: Can't do that atm.

Comment: Can you share the settings for the two tasks?

Comment: Updated the post above with link to Google Drive with the configuration files